# Injeção de Dependência e Repositório Genérico Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, injeção-de-dependência

Tenho uma aplicação windows forms onde estou tentando usar injeção de dependência para alguns serviços, para isso fiz a seguinte configuração inicialmente em Program.cs eu registro os serviços:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigureServices(services);

    using (ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
    {
        var mainForm = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainForm>();
        Application.Run(mainForm);
    }
}

private static void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<AnalisarDbContext>();

    services.AddSingleton<MainForm>();
    services.AddScoped<Form1>();
    services.AddScoped<Form2>();
    services.AddScoped<Form3>();

    services.AddSingleton<IEmpRepository, EmprRepository>();
    services.AddSingleton<ISisRepository, SisRepository>();
}
```

Até aqui tudo funcionando, existem 3 Forms que fiz para testar as funcionalidades, no Form1 eu injeto os serviços que preciso:

```
private readonly ISisRepository _sisRepository;
private readonly IEmpRepository _empRepository;
public SelecionarEmpresa(ISisRepository sistRepository,
                         IEmpRepository empRepository)
{
    _sisRepository= sistRepository;
    _empRepository = empRepository;

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

E a ideia é utilizar por exemplo o _sisRepository para atualizar um registro, na primeira vez que eu salvo funciona, se eu clicar pra salvar novamente, é disparado uma exception, antes de por a exceção já informo que estou usando um repositório genérico, que é o seguinte:

```
public abstract class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity, new()
{
    protected readonly AnalistDbContext Db;
    protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;
    protected Repository(AnalistDbContext db)
    {
        Db = db;
        DbSet = db.Set<TEntity>();

        Db.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

    }
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Buscar(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(predicate).AsNoTracking().ToList();
    }

    public virtual TEntity ObterPorId(Guid id)
    {
        return DbSet.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
    }

    public virtual List<TEntity> ObterTodos()
    {
        return DbSet.AsNoTracking().ToList();
    }

    public void Adicionar(TEntity entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
        SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Atualizar(TEntity entity)
    {
        DbSet.Update(entity);
        SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Remover(Guid id)
    {
        DbSet.Remove(new TEntity { Id = id });
        SaveChanges();
    }
    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return Db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Db?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

A exception é a seguinte:

> [image: Exceprion lançada no Update]

Apesar da clareza da mensagem não consegui entender se este é um problema causado por estar usando injeção de dependência no construtor do Form e ter causado algum problema quanto a instância do repositório, parece que meu objeto ainda é o mesmo já anteriormente instanciado, pois como já falei, este erro ocorre somente na segunda chamada.
Se este realmente for o problema, como poderia resolver? Ou em tratando-se de windows forms eu abandonaria o uso de injeção de dependência?

Comment: coloquei uma resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acontece isso em programação Desktop, porque a entidade já está em seu `Context` e não foi removido na primeira gravação, para que você não tenha esse problema em todas as operações depois do `SaveChanges()` deve chamar o método `Detach` ou mudar o estado desse objeto da seguinte forma:

```
dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Quando se executa um desses dois códigos a entidade não esta sendo tratada no `Context` e por isso não terá o incomodo de uma exceção.

Resumo: em desenvolvimento `Desktop` tem que se atentar aos métodos `Add`, `Update`, `Find` porque os mesmo continuam sendo gerenciados pelo `Context` e se tentar fazer alguma operação nessa entidade pode receber exceção porque a mesma já existe nesse `Context` (geralmente quando você grava um `Id = 1` e tentar fazer alguma operação com esse código, mas, já existe no `Context` e o Entity Framework não deixa).

No seu código algo assim resolve nos métodos `Adicionar` e `Atualizar`, exemplo:

```
public abstract class Repository<TEntity> : 
    IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity, new()
{
    protected readonly AnalistDbContext Db;
    protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;
    protected Repository(AnalistDbContext db)
    {
        Db = db;
        DbSet = db.Set<TEntity>();
        Db.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;    
    }
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Buscar(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(predicate).AsNoTracking().ToList();
    }

    public virtual TEntity ObterPorId(Guid id)
    {
        return DbSet.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
    }

    public virtual List<TEntity> ObterTodos()
    {
        return DbSet.AsNoTracking().ToList();
    }

    public void Adicionar(TEntity entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
        SaveChanges();
        //solução
        Db.Entry(entity) = EntityState.Detached;
    }

    public void Atualizar(TEntity entity)
    {
        DbSet.Update(entity);
        SaveChanges();
        //solução
        Db.Entry(entity) = EntityState.Detached;
    }

    public void Remover(Guid id)
    {
        DbSet.Remove(new TEntity { Id = id });
        SaveChanges();
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return Db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Db?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

inclusive no seu código está correto:

```
return DbSet.Where(predicate).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

utilizar `AsNoTracking()` isso desabilita a verificação pelo `Context` e o desempenho melhora significamente, pois é um dado somente leitura.

- [ObjectContext.Detach(Object) Método](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectcontext.detach?view=netframework-4.8)
- [How do I detach objects in Entity Framework Code First?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599147/how-do-i-detach-objects-in-entity-framework-code-first)
- [EF 4.1 - Entendendo o ciclo de vida das entidades](http://www.macoratti.net/11/11/ef4_cve1.htm)

Comment: Ótima explicação, muito obrigado por compartilhar.